# Aligning Articles In HTML

Tags: html, css, alignment

Ok so basically I've been messing around with HTML and i've been trying to mimic those sites with the image slider and then text at the bottom (not important) and I've come accross something that i can't align properly. I've tried making it a list and using various CSS methods. Here is my code so far (ignore the text in it)

HTML:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

<section id="main">

      <article class="signup">
            <hgroup>
                <h1>Sign Up Now!</h1>
                <h2>Stay Updated with the latest news</h2>
            </hgroup>
            <p>Sign up now and be emailed upon a new tutorial and recieve our weekly newsletter! Not only that, but you also
            get to comment and do other cool stuff!</p>
            <footer>
                <a href="#">Sign Up</a>
            </footer>
       </article>
        <article class="tuts">
            <hgroup>
                <h1>Follow Some Tutorials</h1>
                <h2>Learn Some!</h2>
            </hgroup>
            <p>This site offers many tutorials from Programmming to Physics to Chemistry to Networking to basically anything, and
            you guys also get to vote for some new tutorials!</p>
            <footer>
                <a href="#">Tutorials</a>
            </footer>
       </article>
  </section>

</body>
```

And the CSS:

```
#main article{
    float: left;
    display: block;
    padding: 0; 
    padding-left: 20px;

}

#main{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align:middle;
    clear: both;
}
.signup{
    width: 33%;
    height: auto;
    margin-right: 66%;
    padding-left: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 33%;
    display: block;
}
.tuts{
    width: 33%;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 33%;
    margin-right: 33%;
    text-align: left;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 33%;
    display: block;
}
```

As it seems to be unclear, I am asking to basically align the articles so that there is no padding/margin above the tutorials section of the code provided. So basically similiar to a navmenu, where the list is aligned (I have done this using the CSS code, but it doesn't work for this for some reason). So if it isn't clear, basically just aligning the two articles so they touch side by side, with no margins on top of either, or below either. Just in a vertical alignment.

Im sorry, I don't really know how to explain it, but i hope what i provided should be enough. :/

Comment: Do you want the `article`s on top of each other or next to each other?

Comment: Per the spec, you should have one footer per page.

Comment: @RyanB The footers are for the articles, and are not for the page. This is acceptable, and I Have checked multiple times on this.

Comment: @Tyriar Next to eachother

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get them to 'float' side-by-side, simply remove the `margin`s from your `article`s.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZjLtV/1/

```
.signup{
    width: 33%;
    height: auto;
    /*margin-right: 66%;*/
    padding-left: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 33%;
    display: block;
}
.tuts{
    width: 33%;
    height: auto;
    /*margin-left: 33%;
    margin-right: 33%;*/
    text-align: left;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 33%;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, That simple :C. I was using the margins as i thought it would most likely be needed, but i guess not. Thank you!